# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting T_FUNCTION in error.php

Tags: joomla, localhost, syntax-error

Need a little help here. It would be greatly appreciated. I'm helping out a friend on her project that she got from a client and keep getting this error. Were using the localhost.

Error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting T_FUNCTION in C:\xampp\htdocs\OurCammbackup\libraries\joomla\error\error.php on line 53

Code:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Platform
 * @subpackage  Error
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters, Inc. Allrights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE
 */

 defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;

 // Error Definition: Illegal Options
 define('JERROR_ILLEGAL_OPTIONS', 1);
 // Error Definition: Callback does not exist
 define('JERROR_CALLBACK_NOT_CALLABLE', 2);
 // Error Definition: Illegal Handler
 define('JERROR_ILLEGAL_MODE', 3);

 /**
  * Error Handling Class
  *
  * This class is inspired in design and concept by patErrorManager <http://www.php-       tools.net>
  *
  * patErrorManager contributors include:
  * - gERD Schaufelberger   <gerd@php-tools.net>
  * - Sebastian Mordziol    <argh@php-tools.net>
  * - Stephan Schmidt       <scst@php-tools.net>
  *
  * @package     Joomla.Platform
  * @subpackage  Error
  * @since       11.1
  * @deprecated  12.1   Use PHP Exception
  */
    abstract class JError
 {


/**
 * Legacy error handling marker
 *
 * @var    boolean  True to enable legacy error handling using JError, false to use exception handling.  This flag
 *                  is present to allow an easy transition into exception handling for code written against the
 *                  existing JError API in Joomla.
 * @since  11.1
 */
public static $legacy = false;

/**
 * Array of message levels
 *
 * @var    array
 * @since  11.1
 */
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with the file itself. Has she made any changes to any core Joomla files? Has she developed any of her own extensions or made any changes to 3rd party ones? Is she using the most up to date Joomla version? (2.5.14 or 3.1.5)

Comment: If that is the entire file, then it has been corrupted. I would download that version of joomla from joomla.org and copy the file from that build over to replace this one.

Answer (score 0):

*You don't mention a version but in the 3.x series that file is in the `legacy` directory not the `joomla` directory of the `/libraries`, so I'm going with 2.5.x*

To answer you question, "Yes you are missing something" - the rest of the file. That file is from the 2.5.x series of Joomla and should be over 900 lines long as shown below by the 2.5.14 version:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Platform
 * @subpackage  Error
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE
 */

defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;

// Error Definition: Illegal Options
define('JERROR_ILLEGAL_OPTIONS', 1);
// Error Definition: Callback does not exist
define('JERROR_CALLBACK_NOT_CALLABLE', 2);
// Error Definition: Illegal Handler
define('JERROR_ILLEGAL_MODE', 3);

/**
 * Error Handling Class
 *
 * This class is inspired in design and concept by patErrorManager <http://www.php-tools.net>
 *
 * patErrorManager contributors include:
 * - gERD Schaufelberger    <gerd@php-tools.net>
 * - Sebastian Mordziol <argh@php-tools.net>
 * - Stephan Schmidt        <scst@php-tools.net>
 *
 * @package     Joomla.Platform
 * @subpackage  Error
 * @since       11.1
 * @deprecated  12.1   Use PHP Exception
 */
abstract class JError
{
    /**
     * Legacy error handling marker
     *
     * @var    boolean  True to enable legacy error handling using JError, false to use exception handling.  This flag
     *                  is present to allow an easy transition into exception handling for code written against the
     *                  existing JError API in Joomla.
     * @since  11.1
     */
    public static $legacy = false;

    /**
     * Array of message levels
     *
     * @var    array
     * @since  11.1
     */
    protected static $levels = array(E_NOTICE => 'Notice', E_WARNING => 'Warning', E_ERROR => 'Error');

    protected static $handlers = array(
        E_NOTICE => array('mode' => 'ignore'),
        E_WARNING => array('mode' => 'ignore'),
        E_ERROR => array('mode' => 'ignore')
    );

    protected static $stack = array();

    /**
     * Method to determine if a value is an exception object.  This check supports
     * both JException and PHP5 Exception objects
     *
     * @param   mixed  &$object  Object to check
     *
     * @return  boolean  True if argument is an exception, false otherwise.
     *
     * @since   11.1
     *
     * @deprecated  12.1
     */
    public static function isError(& $object)
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::isError() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        // Supports PHP 5 exception handling
        return $object instanceof Exception;
    }

    /**
     * Method for retrieving the last exception object in the error stack
     *
     * @param   boolean  $unset  True to remove the error from the stack.
     *
     * @return  mixed  Last exception object in the error stack or boolean false if none exist
     *
     * @deprecated  12.1
     * @since   11.1
     */
    public static function getError($unset = false)
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::getError() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        if (!isset(JError::$stack[0]))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if ($unset)
        {
            $error = array_shift(JError::$stack);
        }
        else
        {
            $error = &JError::$stack[0];
        }
        return $error;
    }

    /**
     * Method for retrieving the exception stack
     *
     * @return  array  Chronological array of errors that have been stored during script execution
     *
     * @deprecated  12.1
     * @since   11.1
     */
    public static function getErrors()
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::getErrors() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        return JError::$stack;
    }

    /**
     * Method to add non-JError thrown JExceptions to the JError stack for debugging purposes
     *
     * @param   JException  &$e  Add an exception to the stack.
     *
     * @return  void
     *
     * @since       11.1
     * @deprecated  12.1
     */
    public static function addToStack(JException &$e)
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::addToStack() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        JError::$stack[] = &$e;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new JException object given the passed arguments
     *
     * @param   integer  $level      The error level - use any of PHP's own error levels for
     *                               this: E_ERROR, E_WARNING, E_NOTICE, E_USER_ERROR,
     *                               E_USER_WARNING, E_USER_NOTICE.
     * @param   string   $code       The application-internal error code for this error
     * @param   string   $msg        The error message, which may also be shown the user if need be.
     * @param   mixed    $info       Optional: Additional error information (usually only
     *                               developer-relevant information that the user should never see,
     *                               like a database DSN).
     * @param   boolean  $backtrace  Add a stack backtrace to the exception.
     *
     * @return  mixed    The JException object
     *
     * @since       11.1
     * @deprecated  12.1  Use PHP Exception
     * @see         JException
     */
    public static function raise($level, $code, $msg, $info = null, $backtrace = false)
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::raise() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        jimport('joomla.error.exception');

        // Build error object
        $exception = new JException($msg, $code, $level, $info, $backtrace);
        return JError::throwError($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Throw an error
     *
     * @param   object  &$exception  An exception to throw.
     *
     * @return  reference
     *
     * @deprecated  12.1  Use PHP Exception
     * @see     JException
     * @since   11.1
     */
    public static function throwError(&$exception)
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::throwError() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        static $thrown = false;

        // If thrown is hit again, we've come back to JError in the middle of throwing another JError, so die!
        if ($thrown)
        {
            self::handleEcho($exception, array());
            // Inifite loop.
            jexit();
        }

        $thrown = true;
        $level = $exception->get('level');

        // See what to do with this kind of error
        $handler = JError::getErrorHandling($level);

        $function = 'handle' . ucfirst($handler['mode']);
        if (is_callable(array('JError', $function)))
        {
            $reference = call_user_func_array(array('JError', $function), array(&$exception, (isset($handler['options'])) ? $handler['options'] : array()));
        }
        else
        {
            // This is required to prevent a very unhelpful white-screen-of-death
            jexit(
                'JError::raise -> Static method JError::' . $function . ' does not exist.' . ' Contact a developer to debug' .
                '<br /><strong>Error was</strong> ' . '<br />' . $exception->getMessage()
            );
        }
        // We don't need to store the error, since JException already does that for us!
        // Remove loop check
        $thrown = false;

        return $reference;
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper method for the raise() method with predefined error level of E_ERROR and backtrace set to true.
     *
     * @param   string  $code  The application-internal error code for this error
     * @param   string  $msg   The error message, which may also be shown the user if need be.
     * @param   mixed   $info  Optional: Additional error information (usually only
     *                         developer-relevant information that the user should
     *                         never see, like a database DSN).
     *
     * @return  object  $error  The configured JError object
     *
     * @deprecated   12.1       Use PHP Exception
     * @see        raise()
     * @since   11.1
     */
    public static function raiseError($code, $msg, $info = null)
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::raiseError() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        return JError::raise(E_ERROR, $code, $msg, $info, true);
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper method for the {@link raise()} method with predefined error level of E_WARNING and
     * backtrace set to false.
     *
     * @param   string  $code  The application-internal error code for this error
     * @param   string  $msg   The error message, which may also be shown the user if need be.
     * @param   mixed   $info  Optional: Additional error information (usually only
     *                         developer-relevant information that
     *                         the user should never see, like a database DSN).
     *
     * @return  object  The configured JError object
     *
     * @deprecated  12.1  Use PHP Exception
     * @see        JError
     * @see        raise()
     * @since      11.1
     */
    public static function raiseWarning($code, $msg, $info = null)
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::raiseWarning() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        return JError::raise(E_WARNING, $code, $msg, $info);
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper method for the {@link raise()} method with predefined error
     * level of E_NOTICE and backtrace set to false.
     *
     * @param   string  $code  The application-internal error code for this error
     * @param   string  $msg   The error message, which may also be shown the user if need be.
     * @param   mixed   $info  Optional: Additional error information (usually only
     *                         developer-relevant information that the user
     *                         should never see, like a database DSN).
     *
     * @return  object   The configured JError object
     *
     * @deprecated       12.1   Use PHP Exception
     * @see     raise()
     * @since   11.1
     */
    public static function raiseNotice($code, $msg, $info = null)
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::raiseNotice() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        return JError::raise(E_NOTICE, $code, $msg, $info);
    }

    /**
     * Method to get the current error handler settings for a specified error level.
     *
     * @param   integer  $level  The error level to retrieve. This can be any of PHP's
     *                           own error levels, e.g. E_ALL, E_NOTICE...
     *
     * @return  array    All error handling details
     *
     * @deprecated   12.1  Use PHP Exception
     * @since   11.1
     */
    public static function getErrorHandling($level)
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::getErrorHandling() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        return JError::$handlers[$level];
    }

    /**
     * Method to set the way the JError will handle different error levels. Use this if you want to override the default settings.
     *
     * Error handling modes:
     * - ignore
     * - echo
     * - verbose
     * - die
     * - message
     * - log
     * - callback
     *
     * You may also set the error handling for several modes at once using PHP's bit operations.
     * Examples:
     * - E_ALL = Set the handling for all levels
     * - E_ERROR | E_WARNING = Set the handling for errors and warnings
     * - E_ALL ^ E_ERROR = Set the handling for all levels except errors
     *
     * @param   integer  $level    The error level for which to set the error handling
     * @param   string   $mode     The mode to use for the error handling.
     * @param   mixed    $options  Optional: Any options needed for the given mode.
     *
     * @return  mixed  True on success or a JException object if failed.
     *
     * @deprecated  12.1  Use PHP Exception
     * @since   11.1
     */
    public static function setErrorHandling($level, $mode, $options = null)
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::setErrorHandling() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        $levels = JError::$levels;

        $function = 'handle' . ucfirst($mode);

        if (!is_callable(array('JError', $function)))
        {
            return JError::raiseError(E_ERROR, 'JError:' . JERROR_ILLEGAL_MODE, 'Error Handling mode is not known', 'Mode: ' . $mode . ' is not implemented.');
        }

        foreach ($levels as $eLevel => $eTitle)
        {
            if (($level & $eLevel) != $eLevel)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // Set callback options
            if ($mode == 'callback')
            {
                if (!is_array($options))
                {
                    return JError::raiseError(E_ERROR, 'JError:' . JERROR_ILLEGAL_OPTIONS, 'Options for callback not valid');
                }

                if (!is_callable($options))
                {
                    $tmp = array('GLOBAL');
                    if (is_array($options))
                    {
                        $tmp[0] = $options[0];
                        $tmp[1] = $options[1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $tmp[1] = $options;
                    }

                    return JError::raiseError(
                        E_ERROR,
                        'JError:' . JERROR_CALLBACK_NOT_CALLABLE,
                        'Function is not callable',
                        'Function:' . $tmp[1] . ' scope ' . $tmp[0] . '.'
                    );
                }
            }

            // Save settings
            JError::$handlers[$eLevel] = array('mode' => $mode);
            if ($options != null)
            {
                JError::$handlers[$eLevel]['options'] = $options;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Method that attaches the error handler to JError
     *
     * @return  void
     *
     * @deprecated  12.1
     * @see     set_error_handler
     * @since   11.1
     */
    public static function attachHandler()
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::getErrorHandling() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        set_error_handler(array('JError', 'customErrorHandler'));
    }

    /**
     * Method that detaches the error handler from JError
     *
     * @return  void
     *
     * @deprecated  12.1
     * @see     restore_error_handler
     * @since   11.1
     */
    public static function detachHandler()
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::detachHandler() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        restore_error_handler();
    }

    /**
     * Method to register a new error level for handling errors
     *
     * This allows you to add custom error levels to the built-in
     * - E_NOTICE
     * - E_WARNING
     * - E_NOTICE
     *
     * @param   integer  $level    Error level to register
     * @param   string   $name     Human readable name for the error level
     * @param   string   $handler  Error handler to set for the new error level [optional]
     *
     * @return  boolean  True on success; false if the level already has been registered
     *
     * @deprecated  12.1
     * @since   11.1
     */
    public static function registerErrorLevel($level, $name, $handler = 'ignore')
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::registerErrorLevel() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        if (isset(JError::$levels[$level]))
        {
            return false;
        }

        JError::$levels[$level] = $name;
        JError::setErrorHandling($level, $handler);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Translate an error level integer to a human readable string
     * e.g. E_ERROR will be translated to 'Error'
     *
     * @param   integer  $level  Error level to translate
     *
     * @return  mixed  Human readable error level name or boolean false if it doesn't exist
     *
     * @deprecated  12.1
     * @since   11.1
     */

    public static function translateErrorLevel($level)
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::translateErrorLevel() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        if (isset(JError::$levels[$level]))
        {
            return JError::$levels[$level];
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Ignore error handler
     * - Ignores the error
     *
     * @param   object  &$error   Exception object to handle
     * @param   array   $options  Handler options
     *
     * @return  object   The exception object
     *
     * @deprecated  12.1
     * @see     raise()
     * @since   11.1
     */
    public static function handleIgnore(&$error, $options)
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::handleIgnore() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        return $error;
    }

    /**
     * Echo error handler
     * - Echos the error message to output
     *
     * @param   object  &$error   Exception object to handle
     * @param   array   $options  Handler options
     *
     * @return  object  The exception object
     *
     * @deprecated  12.1
     * @see         raise()
     * @since       11.1
     */
    public static function handleEcho(&$error, $options)
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::handleEcho() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        $level_human = JError::translateErrorLevel($error->get('level'));

        // If system debug is set, then output some more information.
        if (defined('JDEBUG'))
        {
            $backtrace = $error->getTrace();
            $trace = '';
            for ($i = count($backtrace) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--)
            {
                if (isset($backtrace[$i]['class']))
                {
                    $trace .= sprintf("\n%s %s %s()", $backtrace[$i]['class'], $backtrace[$i]['type'], $backtrace[$i]['function']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $trace .= sprintf("\n%s()", $backtrace[$i]['function']);
                }

                if (isset($backtrace[$i]['file']))
                {
                    $trace .= sprintf(' @ %s:%d', $backtrace[$i]['file'], $backtrace[$i]['line']);
                }
            }
        }

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
        {
            // output as html
            echo "<br /><b>jos-$level_human</b>: "
                . $error->get('message') . "<br />\n"
                . (defined('JDEBUG') ? nl2br($trace) : '');
        }
        else
        {
            // Output as simple text
            if (defined('STDERR'))
            {
                fwrite(STDERR, "J$level_human: " . $error->get('message') . "\n");
                if (defined('JDEBUG'))
                {
                    fwrite(STDERR, $trace);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "J$level_human: " . $error->get('message') . "\n";
                if (defined('JDEBUG'))
                {
                    echo $trace;
                }
            }
        }

        return $error;
    }

    /**
     * Verbose error handler
     * - Echos the error message to output as well as related info
     *
     * @param   object  &$error   Exception object to handle
     * @param   array   $options  Handler options
     *
     * @return  object  The exception object
     *
     * @deprecated  12.1
     * @see         raise()
     * @since       11.1
     */
    public static function handleVerbose(&$error, $options)
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::handleVerbose() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        $level_human = JError::translateErrorLevel($error->get('level'));
        $info = $error->get('info');

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
        {
            // Output as html
            echo "<br /><b>J$level_human</b>: " . $error->get('message') . "<br />\n";

            if ($info != null)
            {
                echo "&#160;&#160;&#160;" . $info . "<br />\n";
            }

            echo $error->getBacktrace(true);
        }
        else
        {
            // Output as simple text
            echo "J$level_human: " . $error->get('message') . "\n";
            if ($info != null)
            {
                echo "\t" . $info . "\n";
            }

        }

        return $error;
    }

    /**
     * Die error handler
     * - Echos the error message to output and then dies
     *
     * @param   object  &$error   Exception object to handle
     * @param   array   $options  Handler options
     *
     * @return  object  The exception object
     *
     * @deprecated  12.1
     * @see         raise()
     * @since       11.1
     */
    public static function handleDie(&$error, $options)
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::handleDie() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        $level_human = JError::translateErrorLevel($error->get('level'));

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
        {
            // Output as html
            jexit("<br /><b>J$level_human</b>: " . $error->get('message') . "<br />\n");
        }
        else
        {
            // Output as simple text
            if (defined('STDERR'))
            {
                fwrite(STDERR, "J$level_human: " . $error->get('message') . "\n");
                jexit();
            }
            else
            {
                jexit("J$level_human: " . $error->get('message') . "\n");
            }
        }

        return $error;
    }

    /**
     * Message error handler
     * Enqueues the error message into the system queue
     *
     * @param   object  &$error   Exception object to handle
     * @param   array   $options  Handler options
     *
     * @return  object  The exception object
     *
     * @deprecated  12.1
     * @see         raise()
     * @since       11.1
     */
    public static function handleMessage(&$error, $options)
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::handleMessage() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        $appl = JFactory::getApplication();
        $type = ($error->get('level') == E_NOTICE) ? 'notice' : 'error';
        $appl->enqueueMessage($error->get('message'), $type);

        return $error;
    }

    /**
     * Log error handler
     * Logs the error message to a system log file
     *
     * @param   object  &$error   Exception object to handle
     * @param   array   $options  Handler options
     *
     * @return  object  The exception object
     *
     * @deprecated  12.1
     * @see         raise()
     * @since       11.1
     */
    public static function handleLog(&$error, $options)
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::handleLog() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        static $log;

        if ($log == null)
        {
            $fileName = date('Y-m-d') . '.error.log';
            $options['format'] = "{DATE}\t{TIME}\t{LEVEL}\t{CODE}\t{MESSAGE}";
            $log = JLog::getInstance($fileName, $options);
        }

        $entry['level'] = $error->get('level');
        $entry['code'] = $error->get('code');
        $entry['message'] = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), array('', '\\n'), $error->get('message'));
        $log->addEntry($entry);

        return $error;
    }

    /**
     * Callback error handler
     * - Send the error object to a callback method for error handling
     *
     * @param   object  &$error   Exception object to handle
     * @param   array   $options  Handler options
     *
     * @return  object  The exception object
     *
     * @deprecated  12.1
     * @see         raise()
     * @since       11.1
     */
    public static function handleCallback(&$error, $options)
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::handleCallback() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        return call_user_func($options, $error);
    }

    /**
     * Display a custom error page and exit gracefully
     *
     * @param   object  &$error  Exception object
     *
     * @return  void
     *
     * @deprecated  12.1
     * @since   11.1
     */
    public static function customErrorPage(&$error)
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::customErrorPage() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        // Initialise variables.
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $document = JDocument::getInstance('error');
        if ($document)
        {
            $config = JFactory::getConfig();

            // Get the current template from the application
            $template = $app->getTemplate();

            // Push the error object into the document
            $document->setError($error);

            @ob_end_clean();
            $document->setTitle(JText::_('Error') . ': ' . $error->get('code'));
            $data = $document->render(false, array('template' => $template, 'directory' => JPATH_THEMES, 'debug' => $config->get('debug')));

            // Failsafe to get the error displayed.
            if (empty($data))
            {
                self::handleEcho($error, array());
            }
            else
            {
                // Do not allow cache
                JResponse::allowCache(false);

                JResponse::setBody($data);
                echo JResponse::toString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Just echo the error since there is no document
            // This is a common use case for Command Line Interface applications.
            self::handleEcho($error, array());
        }
        $app->close(0);
    }

    /**
     * Display a message to the user
     *
     * @param   integer  $level  The error level - use any of PHP's own error levels
     *                   for this: E_ERROR, E_WARNING, E_NOTICE, E_USER_ERROR,
     *                   E_USER_WARNING, E_USER_NOTICE.
     * @param   string   $msg    Error message, shown to user if need be.
     *
     * @return  void
     *
     * @deprecated  12.1
     * @since   11.1
     */
    public static function customErrorHandler($level, $msg)
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::customErrorHandler() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        JError::raise($level, '', $msg);
    }

    /**
     * Render the backtrace
     *
     * @param   integer  $error  The error
     *
     * @return  string  Contents of the backtrace
     *
     * @deprecated  12.1
     * @since   11.1
     */
    public static function renderBacktrace($error)
    {
        // Deprecation warning.
        JLog::add('JError::renderBacktrace() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

        $contents = null;
        $backtrace = $error->getTrace();

        if (is_array($backtrace))
        {
            ob_start();
            $j = 1;
            echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="Table">';
            echo '      <tr>';
            echo '              <td colspan="3" class="TD"><strong>Call stack</strong></td>';
            echo '      </tr>';
            echo '      <tr>';
            echo '              <td class="TD"><strong>#</strong></td>';
            echo '              <td class="TD"><strong>Function</strong></td>';
            echo '              <td class="TD"><strong>Location</strong></td>';
            echo '      </tr>';

            for ($i = count($backtrace) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--)
            {
                echo '      <tr>';
                echo '              <td class="TD">' . $j . '</td>';

                if (isset($backtrace[$i]['class']))
                {
                    echo '      <td class="TD">' . $backtrace[$i]['class'] . $backtrace[$i]['type'] . $backtrace[$i]['function'] . '()</td>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '      <td class="TD">' . $backtrace[$i]['function'] . '()</td>';
                }

                if (isset($backtrace[$i]['file']))
                {
                    echo '              <td class="TD">' . $backtrace[$i]['file'] . ':' . $backtrace[$i]['line'] . '</td>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '              <td class="TD">&#160;</td>';
                }

                echo '      </tr>';
                $j++;
            }

            echo '</table>';
            $contents = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
        }

        return $contents;
    }
}
```